# Is it standard behaviour that adding const to size_t can cause compile failure?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

I recently read cool article:
https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2015/08/20/can-you-see-the-bug/
Playing with reduced version on ideone I got surprising behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    const size_t sz=258;
    string s{sz,'#'};
    assert(2==s.size());
}
```

does not compile, but
same program with const removed compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    size_t sz=258;
    string s{sz,'#'};
    assert(2==s.size());
}
```

So my question is this standard required or just compilers decided that one is a compiler warning and other is an compiler error.

If it helps here are the errors and warnings from  gcc 5.1 (tnx godbolt)

> !!error: narrowing conversion of '258ul' from 'size_t {aka long
>   unsigned int}' to 'char' inside { }

---

> !!warning: narrowing conversion of 'sz' from 'size_t {aka long
>   unsigned int}' to 'char' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]

good guy clang 3.6 gives error in both cases, but the question remains, is one legal and bad C++ and other illegal C++?

Comment: Note that the standard only requires a diagnostic.  It doesn't distinguish between errors and warnings.  The issue was discussed in this bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55783

Comment: The underlying problem is that `string s{32,32,32};` should just work. But `32` is an int and int-to-char is a narrowing conversion. We know that `32` can safely be narrowed, precisely because it's a compile-time constant. For this reason compile-time constants are treated differently. (It's not just `const` - `const sz = rand()` is not a compile-time constant and might overflow when narrowed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::string` has constructors declared as:

```
string::string(std::initializer_list<char>);
string::string(std::size_t, char);
```

When we have list-initialization, the following rule applies:

> `(N3337 [dcl.init.list]/3):` List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. **The applicable constructors are enumerated
>     and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). If a narrowing conversion (see
>     below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.**

The initializer-list constructor is selected due to this rule:

> `(N3337 [over.match.list]/1):` 
>   When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> - **Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class T and the
>     argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.**
> - [...]

Now since the initializer-list constructor is the best choice, but a narrowing conversion is required to convert the argument, the program is ill formed.

However, I don't think that makes one compiler correct and one incorrect:

> `(N3337 [intro.compliance]/8):` A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do
>   not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. **Implementations are required to diagnose programs that
>   use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this International Standard. Having done so, however,
>   they can compile and execute such programs.**

The standard has no concept of a warning vs. an error, so GCC is conformant in issuing a warning diagnostic, then going on to compile the program anyway. Note that GCC *will* issue an error if you pass `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: both yours and ForEveR answers are nice, but I accepted yours for the last paragraph.

Comment: Rather than officially recognizing that implementations were sometimes used for purposes where a certain constraint would make the language more useful, and sometimes used for purposes where it would make the language less useful, the C Standard (and later the C++ Standard) decided to allow implementations to either enforce constraints or not, at their leisure, provided only that they issued a diagnostic which they could let programmers ignore.

Answer (score 3):

There is narrowing here, since `initializer_list<char>` constructor is preffered.

N4296 8.5/17.1

> — If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) braced-init-list, the
>   object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).

Since `string` has constructor, that takes `initializer_list<char>` it will be preffered, since

8.5.4/2

> A constructor is an initializer-list constructor if its first
>   parameter is of type std::initializer_list or reference to possibly
>   cv-qualified std::initializer_list for some type E, and either
>   there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have
>   default arguments (8.3.6). **[ Note: Initializer-list constructors are
>   favored over other constructors in list-initialization (13.3.1.7).**

13.3.1.7/1

> When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized such
>   that 8.5.4 specifies that overload resolution is performed according
>   to the rules in this section, overload resolution selects the
>   constructor in two phases
>
> Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list
>   constructors (8.5.4) of the class T and the argument list consists of
>   the initializer list as a single argument.

and program is ill-formed since

N4296 8.5.4/3.5

> Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The
>   applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen
>   through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). **If a narrowing
>   conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments,
>   the program is ill-formed.**

Basically gcc will only warn on this snippet:

```
int main() {
   const size_t v = 258;
   char c = {v};
}
```

when clang will give error.

Comment: But where is the narrowing conversion? `std::string` has a constructor that takes a `size_t` and a `char`, so those are exact matches.

Comment: @nwp `std::initializer_list` constructors are greedy, so this calls `string::string(std::initializer_list<char>)` rather than `string::string(std::size_t, char)`.

Comment: @TartanLlama: Notes may be non-normative by themselves, but a note of the form "[Note: see rule X (13.3.1.7)] can certainly refer to a normative part of the standard.

Comment: @MSalters sure, but why not quote the part which is normative?

Comment: Two common reasons: Often the point to be proven depends on a combination of two related sections of the standard, where one section points to another, and secondly notes are often good summaries.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `std::string` has an initializer lists constructor and it is greedy.  `{sz,'#'}` is being treaated as an initializer list and you are getting a narrowing conversion warning as it is converting `sz` to a char type to make an `std::initializer_list<char>`.  You can fixe this by calling the constrcutor with `()` instead of `{}`

Comment: I know, but that is not the question. My question is if const makes program illformed or not, see TartanLlama answer.